# How do I use python script to get apache's home body data?

Tags: python, json

The content of index.html in apache is:

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Title</title><meta charset="utf8">
</head>

<body>
<p id="show_p">{ "Java": "ad5aedf87c4f591aa51e02daaea31717ee0798cf-40", "Python": "b6525442fc002ca1ea255e90286ab57afd1c952a-12", "Shell": "12d6180f298ab6419c34d6543aca593d81ec446e-10", "JavaScript": "b6525442fc002ca1ea255e90286ab57afd1c952a-13", "C": "6ad83ed9f599a8c9c967ef2f7168127f8dee28f6-229" }</p>
<pre id="out_pre"></pre>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var text = document.getElementById('show_p').innerText;

document.getElementById('show_p').innerText = ''

var result = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(text), null, 2);

document.getElementById('out_pre').innerText= result ;

</script>

</html>
```

Now the  data of index.html is json format.

My python script is this :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2
import json
import os

req = urllib2.Request('http://127.0.0.1')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()
print (the_page)
dictionfo = json.loads(the_page)
```

**print (the_page)** prints everything from index.html

Currently I just want to get the content of body in index.html, how python script should write ？

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library.

Add these lines before `json.loads`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(the_page, 'html.parser')
the_page = soup.p.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

```
from lxml import html, etree

# page loading ...

doc = html.fromstring(the_page) # parse the page to html object
print(etree.tostring(doc.body)) # printing the body
```

With this you can access the different parts of the page as properties or select target elements (for example) with xpath:

```
doc.xpath(./body/div')
```

would return a list with all the divs directly inside the body element. To access attributes of those objects you can use `get('<attributeName>')`.